# xcode RestKit null value when map with web service

Tags: xcode, restkit

Dear i used RestKit to connect on webservice in example it is ok 
when i connect to other webservice it seems it get an empty array

when i use

```
SimpleAccount* account = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
```

it get a

```
[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array exception
```

so have any way to check on the mapping before call it  .

Comment: I'm not sure what is being asked here. Do you want to check if the array does contain any object or you have issues with RestKit?

Comment: when i get data from webservice using Reskit i found it empty so how can i check the maping is correct or maybe some element is null

Comment: check the logs (RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/*", RKLogLevelTrace);) and/or post your mapping and json in your question.

Comment: thank you very much "mja"  it is work now

Comment: but when i print out i get null values how ever in log i have values mapped to the field